# How show data top to bottom after (setReverseLayout=true)

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I wanted to display Firebase Database last child, first in RecyclerView and I set (setReverseLayout=true) and it worked. But I got result like this. how set it top to bottom.

[image]

Comment: As I see it's reversed, right? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass list in Adapter , just Reverse the Arraylist , not the RecyclerView
Like just Before Passing List To RecyclerAdapter , Write This Line first
Collections.reverse(YOUR_LIST);

Comment: Revers is fine. the thing is RecyclerView show data from bottom to top. I want show it top to bottom on  recyclerView.